# Outlook plugin VSTO - How to show up listbox inside window 'New E-Mail"

Tags: vsto

Is it possible to show up my own Listbox or other component in the 'New E-Mail' window in Content field by C# or WinApi?

I guess I have to get handler to this control, create new Listbox and set parent as "content" component. I cannot do progress in my project without it. I need help.

```
Outlook.MailItem oMail = this.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [Custom Pane](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942846.aspx) to the new Email inspector window to display a user control with your list box control. Or use [AddinExpress Regions](http://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-regions/index.php).